# Stop SQL Triggers on Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, remote-server

I'm trying to get a pair of spatially enabled tables to update one another without creating a recursive loop. I have triggers on both the local and the remote server that fire when there's an update, insert, or delete because I need each action handled slightly differently.

So far, I've tried this....

```
begin try
drop trigger sde.PolygonDeleteTrigger
end try
Begin catch
end catch

GO 

CREATE TRIGGER sde.PolygonDeleteTrigger
ON sde.Polygons
AFTER DELETE

AS
BEGIN
declare @GUID nvarchar(max), -- GUGUID
@sqlString nvarchar(max)

set @GUID = (select GUID from deleted ) 

insert into openquery(remoteServer,'select GUID,TimeStamp from myDB.dbo._PolygonTriggerStatus')
values(@GUID,getDate())

if (select count(GUID) from sde._PolygonTriggerStatus where GUID = @GUID) = 0
BEGIN

 set @sqlString = 'delete from openquery(remoteServer, ''select GUID from myDB.dbo.Polygons where GUID = ''''' + @GUID + ''''' '' )'
print @sqlString 
 execute sp_sqlexec @sqlString

END

set @sqlString = 'delete from openquery(remoteServer,''select GUID,TimeStamp from myDB.dbo._PolygonTriggerStatus where GUID = ''''' + @GUID + ''''' '' )' 
print @sqlString 
execute sp_sqlexec @sqlString

END

GO
```

The result is that I get the error message: Transaction context in use by another session.

I thought that adding the trigger status table would alleviate the issue by preventing the insert, update, and delete queries from altering the records when the GUID (GlobalID) of the record in question is present. I still get the message that "Transaction context in use by another session."

So far, I haven't found any good way to prevent the trigger on a remote server from firing.

Any thoughts?

SQL Server: 2008 Express r2

Comment: first thought would be not to use triggers and to do update/delete/insert through stored procedures to handle what you need.  if you are just trying to keep data in synch you could look at replication, running sql agent jobs to do it every x# of minutes to synch them/update as desired.  if you have to do trigger you would probably have to create a table lock disable the trigger on one server make the modifications and re-enable the trigger but again NOT ideal

Comment: Not good idea. Rewrite your solution. For example create table with deleted guids only and procedure on linked server which can use this table. And your error - loopback linked servers cannot be used in a distributed transaction.

Comment: Part of the issues I have is that one of the databases needs to be in the DBO schema and the other in the SDE schema. It's not ideal, but my concern is that replication may not work in this condition. Also, because I'm working with ArcSDE databases, I can't alter (insert, update, or delete) more than one record at a time. At least, not in an unversioned environment.